# Scrapy FormRequest login not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to log in with Scrapy but am receiving lots of "Redirecting (302)" messages. This happens when I use my real login and also with fake login info. I also tried it with another site and still no luck.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'SOlogin'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']

    login_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f'
    test_url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(url=self.login_url, callback=self.parse_login)

    def parse_login(self, response):
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={"email": "XXXXX", "password": "XXXXX"}, callback=self.start_crawl)

    def start_crawl(self, response):
       yield Request(self.test_url, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print("Test URL " + response.url)
```

I also tried adding

```
meta = {'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list':[302]}
```

to the initial Request and the FormRequest.

Here's the output from the code above:

> 2017-04-17 21:48:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started
>   (bot: stackoverflow) 2017-04-17 21:48:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO:
>   Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'stackoverflow', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE':
>   'stackoverflow.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['stackoverflow.spiders'],
>   'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'} 2017-04-17 21:48:17 [scrapy.middleware]
>   INFO: Enabled extensions: ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats'] 2017-04-17 21:48:17
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2017-04-17
>   21:48:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2017-04-17 21:48:17
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: [] 2017-04-17
>   21:48:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2017-04-17 21:48:17
>   [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
>   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2017-04-17 21:48:17
>   [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
>   127.0.0.1:6023 2017-04-17 21:48:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f>
>   (referer: None) 2017-04-17 21:48:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG:
>   Crawled (200) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=&email=XXXXX&password=XXXXX>
>   (referer:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f)
>   2017-04-17 21:48:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG:
>   Redirecting (302) to http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2fask>
>   from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask> 2017-04-17 21:48:19
>   [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2fask>
>   from http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2fask>
>   2017-04-17 21:48:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2fask>
>   (referer:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=&email=XXXXX&password=XXXXX) Test
>   URL
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=anon_ask&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2fask
>   2017-04-17 21:48:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider
>   (finished) 2017-04-17 21:48:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping
>   Scrapy stats: {'downloader/request_bytes': 1772, 
>   'downloader/request_count': 5,  'downloader/request_method_count/GET':
>   5,  'downloader/response_bytes': 34543,  'downloader/response_count':
>   5,  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3, 
>   'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,  'finish_reason':
>   'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 17, 18, 48, 19,
>   470354),  'log_count/DEBUG': 6,  'log_count/INFO': 7, 
>   'request_depth_max': 2,  'response_received_count': 3, 
>   'scheduler/dequeued': 5,  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 5, 
>   'scheduler/enqueued': 5,  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5, 
>   'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 17, 18, 48, 17, 386516)}
>   2017-04-17 21:48:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed
>   (finished)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy by default try to populate your email and password in the first clickable input field (in login page it's search form). You need to specify input field by `formname` or `formid` e.g.
`FormRequest.from_response(response, formid="login-form", formdata={"email": "XXXXX", "password": "XXXXX"}, callback=self.start_crawl)`.
[See docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-subclasses)